# KDE Connect Cannot Use SD Card?

Tags: internal-storage, 7.0-nougat, linux, internal-sd

I'm using KDE connect from my Kubuntu 18.04 desktop to try and connect to my tablet (Tab A 10.1 running Android version 7). The internal SD card registers (I can see it) in Dolphin (File Explorer), but I can't read or write to the directory, and I get an error when I try to do so.

From what I recall, this may be due to an Android security policy. Is this what is occurring? Is there any way to use KDE connect to access the SD card? (My tablet has very little internal memory)

Comment: Is the phone connected in USB charging mode? Changing it to MTP should do the trick

Comment: Having same issue. Its a bug https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=377058